# Postgres LEFT JOIN as json object property

Tags: postgresql

We have two tables:

```
book: id | title| author_id
authors: id | name
```

How to left join authors for one-to-one relation into property of object book with 'author' alias:

```
{
  id
  title
  author_id
  author: {id, name}
}
```

Current query result is:

```
 {
      id
      title
      author_id
      a_id
      name
 }
```

Query example

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, a.id as a_id, a.name
FROM books b  
LEFT JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id
WHERE b.id=1
```

Comment: With `a.name` instead of `a,name`  it'll work

Comment: Also `LEFT JOIN author a ON a.id = a.author_id` should be `LEFT JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id`

Comment: What do you mean by "object property"? SQL only knows rows. What data type do you expect your `author` column to have?

Comment: @Bergi i want response object in format i described.

Comment: result of current query is object with {id, title, name}, i need to move author fields in it's own property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string functions for combining multiple values in one column:

```
SELECT b.id, title, author_id, format('{%s, %s}', a.id, a.name) AS author
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id
WHERE b.id = 1
```

I suspect you were actually looking for JSON format though:

```
SELECT b.id, title, author_id, json_build_object('id', a.id, 'name', a.name) AS author
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN author a ON a.id = b.author_id
WHERE b.id = 13
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7723777563f99aa07ac64c2c0ff78de0))